# From chromote to rvest

Tags: web-scraping, rvest, chromote

With *chromote*, I should be able to obtain the HTML codes of a website like this (if I'm not mistaken):

```
library(chromote)
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
b$view()
b$Page$navigate("https://www.ooir.org/")
x <- b$DOM$getDocument()
```

Is it possible to then use *rvest* to conduct basic webscraping tasks, in terms of ...

```
x %>%
   html_nodes("a")
```

Of course, the above two lines do not work.

What I want to achieve is to open a webpage in *chromote* to subsequently extract information with *rvest*.

Answer (score 2):

One method to retrieve html is through Chromote javascript evaluation:

```r
library(chromote)
library(rvest)
b <- ChromoteSession$new()
{
  b$Page$navigate("https://www.ooir.org/")
  b$Page$loadEventFired()
} 
#> $timestamp
#> [1] 73090.44

# evaluate js in Chromeote and work with returned string
b$Runtime$evaluate("document.querySelector('html').outerHTML")$result$value %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements("a") %>% 
  head()
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <a href="index.php">\n                        <div class="float-o1">O</di ...
#> [2] <a href="index.php" class="active_menu">Trending Research</a>
#> [3] <a href="journals.php">Journal Rankings</a>
#> [4] <a href="about.php">About</a>
#> [5] <a href="#" class="clicksmall" onclick="show()"><b>Field of Research</b>: ...
#> [6] <a href="index.php?field=Agricultural+Sciences" class="clicksmall">Agricu ...
```

You could also work with `b$DOM`, missing link between that and `rvest` looks something like this:

```r
x <- b$DOM$getDocument()

x$root$nodeId %>% 
  b$DOM$querySelector("html") %>% 
  `[[`(1) %>% 
  b$DOM$getOuterHTML() %>% 
  `[[`(1) %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_elements("a") %>% 
  head()

#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <a href="index.php">\n                        <div class="float-o1">O</di ...
#> [2] <a href="index.php" class="active_menu">Trending Research</a>
#> [3] <a href="journals.php">Journal Rankings</a>
#> [4] <a href="about.php">About</a>
#> [5] <a href="#" class="clicksmall" onclick="show()"><b>Field of Research</b>: ...
#> [6] <a href="index.php?field=Agricultural+Sciences" class="clicksmall">Agricu ...
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>